# Selecting Dimension goes to column label instead of row in Excel ( SSAS )

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, olap-cube

selecting a dimension attribute for SSAS  excel  is going to column label instead of row label on pivot table . It used to work correct before i added an new attribute to the dimension.  Can someone tell me what property should i change to default it to row label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Dimension in BIDS. In the Dimension properties, change Type to something other than Time.